# What is the minimal polynomial of A?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $f$ be an endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with its matrix $A$ in the canonical basis $\mathcal{B}$ as
>   $$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & - 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
>   What is the minimal polynomial of $f$?

The characteristic polynomial of $f$ is: 
$$P_{f}(X) = (1 - X)(X - 2)^2.$$

The minimal polynomial $m_{f}$ is the polynomial with the least degree that  divides $P_{f}$, has the eigenvalues of $f$ as roots and $m_{f}(A) = 0$.

In this case, we have $m_{f}(X)= (1 - X)(2 - X)$ but $m_f(f) \neq 0 $.

How can I find the minimal polynomial of $A$ and what is the fastest method to determine it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate minimal polynomial of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275809/calculate-minimal-polynomial-of-a-matrix)

Comment: The minimal polynomial is either $1-X, 2-X, (2-X)^2, (1-X)(2-X)$ or $(1-X)(2-X)^2$, just because the minimal polynomial must divide the characteristic polynomial. You can try each of these out, insert $A$ and see which one is the first one to evaluate to $0$.

Comment: Why do you say $m_{f}(X)=(1-X)(2-X)$ when the quadratic *doesn't* kill $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since :

- $m_f$ divides $P_f$;
- they share the same roots;
- $m_f$ is [monic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial),

one can conclude that, in this case, there are only two possibilites :

- either $m_f(X) = (1-X)(X-2)$
- or $m_f(X) = (1-X)(X-2)^2$

Now which one is it ? Well, plug in $f$ in the first one. This doesn't evaluate to $0$, so the only possibility left is $m_f = P_f$, which we know evaluate to $0$ when we plug in $f$.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $A$ has eigenvalues 1,2,2. as minimal polynomial of $A$ has the eigenvalues of $A$ as roots and divides characteristic polynomial so only possibilities for minimal polynomial are :

$m_f(X)$ = $(X-1)(X-2)$ or $(X-1)(X-2)^2$

**For eigenvalue 2**  
Algebraic multiplicity = 2
Geometric Multiplicity = 3 [no. of columns in A] -  $\rho(A-2I)$ [Rank of $A-2I$] = 3 - 2 = 1
this gives A.M. is not equal to G.M so $A$ is not diagonalizable and only option left is

$m_f(X) =  (X-1)(X-2)^2$

> **NOTE:** matrix $A$ is diagonalizable iff it contains only linear factors in it's minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Your minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial have same roots. This what you can use then you have to check whether the matrix vanishes at $(1-X)(2-X)$ or not. In general otherwise, you have to use Jordan-Block theorem and see what is the dimension of each eigenspace. Most of the cases it is calculative.

Comment: But $m_f(f) \neq 0 $. Which means it's not the minimal polynomial.

Comment: $m_f(f)$ is a non zero polynomial. Why would it be zero? See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)

Comment: If you do not have any more doubts, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial agree, which is equivalent to each eigenvalue occurring in exactly one Jordan block.

$$
R =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1  & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
R^{-1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0  & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and
$$  R^{-1} A R = J. $$

$$
J =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0  & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The direction that is actually useful is $R J R^{-1} = A.$ Useful for finding $e^A$ or $A^{100}$ or any $f(A)$ with $f$ single-variable analytic.

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1  & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0  & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0  & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
3 & 1  & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$