# minimal and characteristic polynomial of this operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial, companion-matrices

The following is Problem 18 from Chap8.C of Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*.

---

[image: Chap8.C-Problem 18]

---

***Edited to add a transcription of the original problem(in the image)***

---

**P18.** Suppose $a_0, a_1, ...., a_{n-1} \in \mathbb{C}$, find the minimal and characteristic polynomials of the operator on $\mathbb{C}^n$ whose matrix form (w.r.t the standard basis) is

$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & & &  & & -a_0\\
1 & 0 & & & & -a_1 \\
  & 1 & \ddots & &  & -a_2 \\
  &   & \ddots & &  & \vdots \\
  &   &        & & 0 & -a_{n-2}\\
  &   &        & & 1 & -a_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

---

Denote the given matrix form of the operator as $A$, then its characteristic polynomial (I think) can be obtained by induction and Row Expansion on the first row of the determinant $det(A-\lambda I)$. If I'm not mistake, the characteristic polynomial should be
$$q(z) = z^n  +a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + ..... + a_1 z + a_0$$

(1)**How to get the minimal polynomials**? The characteristic polynomial $q(z)$ should be a multiple of the minimal polynomial $p(z)$, but there's nothing to do in factorizing $q(z)$.

In Axler's book the only method to find the minimal polynomial mentioned is to find the linear dependency of $A, A^2, ..., A^n$ for the minimum integer $n$. And also here's another related method I found in another post [finding the minimal polynomial without using the characteristic polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4439598/637630), where it's recommended to find the linear dependency of $v, Av, A^2 v, ...$ for some vector $v$. However either way, it's a bit overwhelming in calculations, as the entries in the last column will explode with increasing power of $A$.

(2) I heard Axler's known for his aversion in matrices and related operations (e.g. determinant). As expected, there is very few mentioning of matrix operations. **I wonder if there are other ways to find the characteristic polynomial (and also the minimal polynomial) for this operator, without referring to calculating the $det(A-\lambda I)$**. (I tried to find each eigenvalue of $A$ based on the fact that $(A-\lambda I)$ is not invertible/injective/surjective if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, but the characteristic polynomial $p(z)$ I get above may suggest the eigenvalues are not of simple forms of $a_0, a_1, a_2, ...., a_{n-1}$)

Any hint and help would be appreciated, and thanks ahead.

Comment: You don't need to compute $A^k$ in order to find $A^kv$, since the latter can be computed as $A(A(\ldots A(V)\ldots))$. In particular if you choose $v$ to be the first vector of the standard basis of $\mathbf{C}^n$, you can find $A^kv$ for all $k<n$ without ever needing the last column of the companion matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$Let $e_{0}, e_{1}, \dots , e_{n-1}$ be the standard basis of $\C^{n}$. Note that $$A e_{0} = e_{1}, A e_{1} = e_{2}, \dots, A e_{n-2} = e_{n-1}.$$

Therefore if $p \in \C[x]$ is a polynomial, the following are equivalent

- $p(A) = 0$, and
- $p(A) e_{0} = 0$.

This is because if $p(A) e_{0} = 0$, then $0 = A 0 = A p(A) e_{0} = p(A) A e_{0} = p(A) e_{1}$, etc.

If $0 \ne p \in \C(x)$ has degree less than $n$, say
$p = p_{0} + p_{1} x +  \dots + p_{n-1} x^{n-1}$, then
\begin{align}
p(A) e_{0} 
&= 
(p_{0} + p_{1} A +  \dots + p_{n-1} A^{n-1}) e_{0}
\\&=
p_{0} e_{0} + p_{1} A e_{0} +  \dots + p_{n-1} A^{n-1} e_{0}
\\&=
p_{0}e_{0} + p_{1} e_{1} +  \dots + p_{n-1} e_{n-1} \ne 0,
\end{align}
as $p \ne 0$.

Now note that
\begin{align}
A^{n} e_{0}
&=
A A^{n-1} e_{0}
=
A e_{n-1} 
\\&=
-a_{0} e_{0} - a_{1} e_{1} - \dots - a_{n-1} e_{n-1}
\\&=
-a_{0} e_{0} - a_{1} A e_{0} - \dots - a_{n-1} A^{n-1} e_{0},
\end{align}
and you're done. (Actually, you have already calculated the characteristic polynomial, so you already know the latter fact.)

Comment: Ohhh, I somehow was trying on $v, Av, A^2 v, ... , A^n v$ for $v = (1, 0, 0,...., 0)^T$ immediately after I posted the question, but failed to reason on such choice of vector $v$. I totally forget about the "Standard Basis" in the question. Your answer is much simpler and more rigorous. It's very helpful. Thank you !

Comment: I'd like to add a bit further explanation on the equivalence between $p(A) = 0$ and $p(A)e_0 = 0$ at the beginning: 1. $p(A)e_i = 0$ for $i = 1, 2, ... , n$ implies that the $span(e0, e1, ..., e_{n-1})$ is a subset of the kernel/null space of $p(A)$ which takes up the whole space $\mathbb{C}^n$, leaving $p(A)$ a zero operator. (the other direction is easy);

Comment: 2.  the resulting vector of $p(A)e_i$ is actually the $i$th column in the matrix representation of $p(A)$.   and  $p(A)e_i = 0$ for $i = 1, 2, ... , n$ follows that the matrix form of $p(A)$ is of all zero column vectors, and thus a zero matrix. (the other direction is easy)